# Spring-xd container(1.3.1) compatibility with Spark 1.6.1+ Hadoop 2.7.2

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spring-boot, maven-3, spring-xd

I am currently working on a spring-xd runtime container, I use:

**Spark 1.6.1+ Hadoop 2.7.2 + Spring-xd 1.3.1**

My questions:

Are these versions compatible to spring-xd container (1.3.1)?

Can these be deployed as a spring-boot in a clustered environment?

Is there any specific bill of materials been recommended for spring-xd to use with spark? I saw some examples which is been used for spark stream in git hub, is that officially released and available in maven central repository or pivotal public repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the more modern form of Spring XD.  Its called Spring Cloud Data Flow.  Its going to be a huge topic at the Spring Platform IO this year.  http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/